# Use of undeclared identifier GDFileSystem while using Blackberry Dynamics

Tags: ios, blackberry, gd, microsoft-dynamics

I am trying to use GD sdk in my app. I have added the GD.bundle into the project. When i build i get an error saying GDFileSystem not found. I am not able to import the GD framework as well in that class.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Swift, use import GD.SecureStore.File and if Objective c, use #import <GD/GDFileManager.h>.